# Select second row of data in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is currently set up to grab the data from the last row in a table. How can I change it to only grab the second row?

```
<script>
$(document).on('globalUpdate', function() {

 $ (".diff").each( function(){
var curr = parseFloat($ 
   this).closest("tr").find("td:last").find(".vertical").text())
var target = parseFloat($ (this).closest("td").find("b:first").text())
if ((target-curr) > 2.0 || (target-curr) < -2.0){
    if ((target-curr) > 3.0 || (target-curr) < -3.0){
        if ((target-curr) < -3.0){
            if ((target-curr) < -6.0){
                $ (this).html("<span style='padding-left: 19px; color:#f02;'>" + String((curr-target).toFixed(2)) +"% <span style='font-size: 15px; color: #A33315; float:right;'>&#9940;</span></span>")
            }
            else {
                $ (this).html("<span style='padding-left: 19px; color:#d50;'>" + String((curr-target).toFixed(2)) +"% <span style='font-size: 15px; color: #A33315; float:right;'>&#9940;</span></span>")
            }
        }
        if ((target-curr) > 3.0){
           if ((target-curr) > 6.0){
                $ (this).html("<span style='padding-left: 19px; color:#f02;'>" + String((curr-target).toFixed(2)) +"% <span style='font-size: 19px; color: #005EA5;font-weight:900; float:right;'>&#8679;</span></span>")
            }
            else {
                $ (this).html("<span style='padding-left: 19px; color:#d50;'>" + String((curr-target).toFixed(2)) +"% <span style='font-size: 19px; color: #005EA5;font-weight:900; float:right;'>&#8679;</span></span>")
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $ (this).html("<span style='color:#980'>" + String((curr-target).toFixed(2)) +"%</span>")
    }
}
else {
    $ (this).html("<span style='color:#060'>" + String((curr- 
target).toFixed(2)) +"%</span>")
}
});

})
function legendVis() {
document.getElementById("legend").style.opacity = ".9";
}
function legendTrans() {
document.getElementById("legend").style.opacity = ".5";
}


function tHs() {
var right = document.getElementsByClassName("table-hdr-cell");
right.getElementsByTagName("span").innnerHTML = "Current";
}

</script>
```

I believe the change needs to occur with the:
    find("td:last")

I've tried changing the last to second, 2nd, and next but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: What does `this` refer to?  What is the HTML?

Comment: share html and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Say your table has an id `myTable` then you can use either

```
$('#myTable tr').eq(1)
```

to find it by index or

```
$('#myTable tr:nth-child(2)')
```

to find it by the `nth` child

Comment: It's probably horrible practice but I got the script to do what I needed if I changed 
    find("td:last") to     find("td:odd").

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, I made an example using `.children()`, you can see below.

```js
$(function(){
  $('table.table tbody').children('tr').eq(1).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">

  <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```